# How to parse string into url.Values in golang?

Tags: parsing, go, url-encoding

Let's suppose i have the following string

`honeypot=&name=Zelalem+Mekonen&email=zola%40programmer.net&message=Hello+And+this+is+a+test+message...`

and i want to convert it into `url.Values` struct and i have the following

```
data := url.Values{}

parameters := strings.Split(request.Body, "&")

for _, parameter := range parameters {

    parts := strings.Split(parameter, "=")

    data.Add(parts[0], parts[1])

}
```

which does convert it into `url.Values` but the problem is that it doesn't convert url encoded values like `+` into space, so first **is there a better way to parse this?** then **if not how do i convert url encoded string to normal string first?**

Thank's For Your Help...o

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use `url.ParseQuery` to convert the raw query to `url.Values` with unescaping

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    t := "honeypot=&name=Zelalem+Mekonen&email=zola%40programmer.net&message=Hello+And+this+is+a+test+message..."
    v, err := url.ParseQuery(t)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

Result:

```
map[honeypot:[] name:[Zelalem Mekonen] email:[zola@programmer.net] message:[Hello And this is a test message...]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first decode the URL with [`net/url/QueryUnescape`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#QueryUnescape).
It does converts '`+`' into '' (space).

Then you can start splitting the decoded string, or use [`net/url/#ParseRequestURI`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#ParseRequestURI) and get the [`URL.Query`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.Query).

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `URL.Query`:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "net/url"
)

func main() {
   get := url.URL{
      RawQuery: "honeypot=&name=Zelalem+Mekonen&email=zola%40programmer.net",
   }
   query := get.Query()
   // map[email:[zola@programmer.net] honeypot:[] name:[Zelalem Mekonen]]
   fmt.Println(query)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/net/url#URL.Query